# Error on loading bootstrap loader, using django (not found the css)

Tags: css, django

I am new with django and python, have create a test project which works well until the point try to change the design like css, js and some img. I installed bootstrap as well, when I upload the three files, css, js and img, The page can not find my css file and others. On my server display this message:

> [30/Jan/2014 11:19:15] "GET /static/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1614
>   [30/Jan/2014 11:19:34] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1655

I tried ti find the css page from developer section on firework which jump to this page:
Page not found (404)
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:

localhost:8000/static/css/bootstrap.css 'css/bootstrap.css' could not be found
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

And below is the link on base.html to the css files.
href="/static/css/bootstrap.css"

Could you please give me an idea what is wrong here, I do appreciate?

Thanks
Dilshad

Comment: It would be nice to know the folder structure of your project, at least the full path of the bootstrap.css file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have your css folder in static folder
and you have this in your settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
'/var/www/static/',
)
```

and you have this in INSTALLED_APPS:

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

then use this in your template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}">
```

more details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for your answer, Unfortunately I have most exactly the same in the setting files only the templates I have include your what you wrote, I have the content but the design is not what is in Bootstrap just display the content in the left hand.

Comment: BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)) INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'join',
    'south',
) STATIC_URL = '/static/'


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'templates'),
) MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static-only')

STATICFIELS_DIR = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/var/www/static', '/var/www/static'),
) that is all my settings file

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.what's in your template? maybe you could check in this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/