# Cannot locate CSS static files for Django page

Tags: django

[image]

I'm currently trying to get the styles to load for my index page and am not having any luck. The above illustrates my current file structure. DEBUG = True and I have run collectstatic to no avail. I'm assuming it's all a basic directory mapping issue, but can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

## settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

## URLS

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from homepage.views import main_page
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', main_page, name = 'home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

## html snippet

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

## ERROR

```
'static/css/bootstrap.css' could not be found
```

Comment: You have `static/static/css/bootstrap.css` in your folder structure, no?

Comment: that is correct, is that a problem?

Comment: try: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/static')`

Comment: You have created another static directory inside the static , that is causing the problem. Remove the extra static directory.

Comment: I removed the second static directory and still get the error.
 <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"> I knew it wasn't an issue, but I know having a single static directory is better.

Comment: remove the second static directory but keep it here `<link href="{% static 'static/css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: But wouldn't that be calling static twice still? Also, it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Have you read the docs about serving static files in development? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/ Have you added this to your urls.py: urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Comment: Just a note: Editing questions in ways that change them significantly is not helpful, as the answers will also need to change. In the future, it would be more helpful to keep your original question intact.

Comment: Yes, I have added the url to my urls file.

Comment: @ryan did you 'django.contrib.staticfiles', to your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: There was never any error, it's just that the page styles will not show. If I open page source and click the link to one of the css files in the page, I get the following: E.G: Request URL: http://localhost:8000/static/css/bootstrap.css
Raised by: django.views.static.serve
'css/bootstrap.css' could not be found

Comment: Do you have a `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting? I think you're confusing `STATIC_ROOT` with `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: No I do not, can you elaborate on what I should change it to?

Comment: Ah static files dirs fixed the issue!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error on loading bootstrap loader, using django (not found the css)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454968/error-on-loading-bootstrap-loader-using-django-not-found-the-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing a couple of staticfiles topics.

First, you need to define `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your **settings.py**. This needs to be different than your `STATIC_ROOT` (which doesn't need to be set in development with `DEBUG = True`):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

If you want to define `STATICFILES_ROOT`, this needs to be different than the above. The `STATICFILES_ROOT` is the location where `collectstatic` will "collect" static files from your `STATICFILES_DIRS`, for production.